# Send android sensor data over UDP socket

Tags: android, sockets, udp, sensors

I'm writing an app to get sensor data from my Android phone (GPS position, accelerometer, orientation) and send the data over UDP to a server (I plan to use Python for that, by the way).

Now, I've managed so far as to obtaining the sensor data and displaying them, but kind of stuck in figuring out a way to combine the various sensor data to a packet, and send the packet over UDP. What I don't know is how to "merge" the data in a way that they could still be identified by the server, e.g. that it comes from the accelerator, or that it's a GPS coordinate, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python on the server side you can pack you values into JSON string like
{
  "sensor": somedata,
  "gps": somedata
}

(Because its pretty easy to deserialize JSON object to dictionary using *json.loads*)

And then put this string to UDP packet

To create JSON string you can use these classes http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi, thanks! Could you please point me out to a good Android JSON tutorial? I googled it myself but can't seem to find a nice step-by-step guide for beginner. Thanks again!

Comment: it is pretty simple, for example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html#write

Answer (score 1):

JSON is good, or you could use Jython to let you take advantage of Java's serialization libraries. The advantage of that is you don't have to do any work to convert your classes to a serializable format, literally just implement serializable and add a serialVersionUID.

Copied from [Jython tips](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2002/04/11/jythontips.html?page=2):

9 Serialization

Java objects cannot be serialized using the standard Python pickle and cPickle modules. Both Java and Jython objects can be serialized using normal Java serialization. However, when deserializing a Jython object you cannot use the normal java.io.ObjectInputStream class, you must use the Jython-specific org.python.util.PythonObjectInputStream, as shown here:

```
import java.io as io
import org.python.util as util

class TestClass(io.Serializable):
    def __init_ _(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
        self.message = "Serialized"

    def toString(self):
        return "Message: %(message)s value: 
          is %(value)s" % self.__dict_ _

instance = TestClass(3)

outFile = io.FileOutputStream("test.ser")
outStream = io.ObjectOutputStream(outFile)
outStream.writeObject(instance)
outFile.close( )

inFile = io.FileInputStream("test.ser")
inStream = util.PythonObjectInputStream(inFile)

readInstance = inStream.readObject( )
print readInstance.toString( )
Message: Serialized value: is 3
```

If you do not use the PythonObjectInputStream, you will get a runtime error because the ordinary Java ObjectInputStream has difficulty finding and recreating the dynamically loaded proxy classes used for Jython's Java inheritance.